# PIL exports pdf file in wrong size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to export an image as a .pdf file in DIN A4 size. For that I am using PIL (python imaging library).

My problem is that the resulting pdf file does not seem to have the correct size. Using 300 DPI the size should be 2480x3507 pixels or 210x297 millimeters.

Depending on the application  I open the file with, I get different sizes:

- Adobe Acrobat Reader: 210x297 millimeters (correct size; please note next error)
- Microsoft Edge: 280x396 millimeters

While the images printed on the page are looking correctly in MS Edge, I only get a fraction of two overlapping images in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

I would like to store the page in DIN A4 and be able to print it out. However, with those wrong sizes the images appear stretched on paper.

To get the image I convert the size of the page (21 x 29.7 cm) into pixels with a given DPI using the following function:

```py
def cm_to_px(centimeters):
    return (300 * centimeters) / 2.54    # pixels with resolution of 300 DPI
```

To paste the images on an A4 paper, I use this code:

```py
# get the page image with the correct size
page = Image.new('1', (cm_to_px(21), cm_to_px(29.7)), 1)

# paste the images on the page
for y in range(0, vertical_per_page):
    for x in range(0, horizontal_per_page):
        page.paste(image, (img_w, img_h))

# save the image as pdf file
page.save('file.pdf', resolution=300)
```

Comment: It's possible PIL can't handle 1-bit monochrome formats for PDF.  If I change the format to `'RGB'` or even `'L'` grayscale, then the overlapping goes away.  When I test on Linux, the file is always recognized as A4.

Comment: @TimRoberts I now switched to RGB for testing and got the correct size in every program I can open pdf files currently with, except Microsoft Edge. Thank you very much for your help!